# Shortest code to generate all Pythagorean triples up to a given limit

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

Generate the shortest possible code in any programming language that can generate all Pythagorean triples with all values not exceeding a given integer limit. A Pythagorean triple is a set of three integers \$(a, b, c)\$ that satisfy the equation \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$. The program should output the triples in any format, such as a list of tuples or a newline-separated list of strings.

Input: An integer limit \$n\$ (1 ≤ \$n\$ ≤ \$10^6\$)

Output: All Pythagorean triples \$(a, b, c)\$ such that \$1 ≤ a, b, c ≤ n\$ and \$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\$.

### Test Cases

```
Input: 20
Output:
(3, 4, 5)
(5, 12, 13)
(6, 8, 10)
(8, 15, 17)
(9, 12, 15)
(12, 16, 20)
```

```
Input: 5
Output:
(3, 4, 5)
```

Note: The output order does not matter as long as all the correct Pythagorean triples are included. Duplicate triples should not be included. But, specifying the order might help.

Comment: Can I output numbers without parentheses like `3,4,5`?

Comment: Suggested test cases: a number less than 5 and a number that isn't equal to any possible \$c\$ value.

Comment: Suggested Test-Case: n=16, because answers iterating only over a and b might produce the wrong solution with c=17

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ɾ3ḋ'²÷ε=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvjPhuIsnwrLDt861PSIsIiIsIjIwIl0=)

I'm surprised I didn't manage to make this horribly inefficient.

*-1 thanks to Kevin!*

### Explained

```
ɾ3ḋ'²÷ε=
ɾ          # Range [1, input]
 3ḋ        # Combinations of length 3
   '       # filtered by:
    ²      #   squaring everything
     ÷     #   dumping the triplet onto the stack in reverse order
      ε    #   absolute difference of b**2 and c**2
       =   #   equals a**2
```

Comment: `^+` can be `ε` for -1 byte (port of my top 05AB1E answer).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen good catch. Didn't think to think that the equation could be written in terms of equalling a squared

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L3.Æʒn`αQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx1jvcNupSXkJ5zYG/v9vZAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H2O9w22nJuUlnNsY@L9W53@0kYGOaSwA).

The last three bytes could alternatively be `RÆ_` for the same byte-count:

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx1jvcNupSXlBh9vi//83MgAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H2O9w22nJuUFHW6L/1@r8z/ayEDHNBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L         # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 3.Æ      # Create all triplet-combinations of this list
    ʒ     # Filter this list of [a,b,c]-triplets by:
     n    #  Square each inner integer in the triplet
      `   #  Push all three values separated to the stack
       α  #  Get the absolute difference of the top two: |b²-c²|
        Q #  Check if it's equal to the third one: a² == |b²-c²|
          # (after which the filtered list of triplets is output implicitly as result)

      R   #  Reverse the triplet to [c²,b²,a²]
       Æ  #  Reduce it by subtracting: c²-b²-a²
        _ #  Check if this is 0
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, 57 bytes

```
[ [1,b] 3 [ 2 v^n first3 -rot + = ] filter-combinations ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsJAEET7fMX0mqAJNopgJzY2YhUiXI5VD5O9uLcG/PrzQrAb3puZu7HqJV4vp/Nxi97osxDDDwoI9P4Q25QmOquRpnbAi4Spm5n1fevYJO5swCCk@h3EsWKXZeUq28Qa9XrZNqhQo8R4Y9ydBK2Qi1cssEeTSKck@f/MeQ5oYusOaVMkn1L8AQ)

- `[1,b] 3 [ ... ] filter-combinations` select combinations of three from \$[1..n]\$ where...
- `2 v^n` square the elements of the triplet
- `first3` place each element onto the stack
- `-rot` move \$c^2\$ from the top of the stack to the bottom
- `+` add \$a^2\$ and \$b^2\$
- `=` equal?

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$13\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 10.70 bytes

```
R1+3zQg2^Au_=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrgwy1jasC043iHEvjbSFiUKkFi4wMICwA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
R1+3zQg2^Au_=  # Implicit input
R1+            # Push range(1, input+1)
   3zQ         # Combinations with length 3
      g        # Filter by:                     STACK: [a, b, c]
       2^      #  Square each                   STACK: [a**2, b**2, c**2]
         Au    #  Dump onto stack               STACK: a**2, b**2, c**2
           _   #  Subtract top two              STACK: a**2, c**2 - b**2
            =  #  Are they equal?               STACK: a**2 == c**2 - b**2
               # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/noether), 62 bytes

```
!aI~n(!a~bn1+({a2^!b2^+0.5^~cn<cn=|cc_=&}{aP","PbP","PcP?}b)a)
```

[Try it in your browser!](https://astrochristian.github.io/noether?code=IWFJfm4oIWF-Ym4xKyh7YTJeIWIyXiswLjVefmNuPGNuPXxjY189Jn17YVAiLCJQYlAiLCJQY1A_fWIpYSk&input=MjA)

Surprisingly this is the first time I've realised the severe lack of \$\leq\$ and \$\geq\$ operators in the language.

**Explanation:**

```
!a                                                             # Initialiase variable a to 1
  I~n                                                          # Store user input in n: outer loop exit condition
     (                                                       ) # Outer loop
      !a~b                                                     # Increment a and store value in b                                                      
          n1+                                                  # Add 1 to n: inner loop exit condition
             (                                             )   # Inner loop
              {                         }{               }     # If ... Else
               a2^                                             # Square a                                     
                  !b2^                                         # Increment value of b and square                       
                      +0.5^                                    # Sum a and b and square root                            
                           ~cn<                                # Store value in c and check if less than n                         
                               cn=                             # c == n                       
                                  |                            # Bitwise OR                   
                                   cc_=                        # c == floor(c)                  
                                       &                       # Bitwise AND                
                                          aP","PbP","PcP?      # If true, output variable values, comma separated
                                                          b    # Push b to stack (inner loop exit condition)
                                                            a  # Push a to stack (outer loop exit condition)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ à3 fÈÌ²Ñ¶Xx²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDgMyBmyMyy0bZYeLI&input=MjAKLVI)

```
õ à3 fÈÌ²Ñ¶Xx²     :Implicit input of integer U
õ                  :Range [1,U]
  à3               :Combinations of length 3
     f             :Filter by
      È            :Passing each X through the following function
       Ì           :  Last element
        ²          :  Square
         Ñ         :  Multiply by 2
          ¶        :  Is equal to
           Xx      :  X reduced by addition
             ²     :  After squaring each
```

Comment: [12 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDgMyBrX22y1HIt&input=MjAgLVI) by (roughly) porting Kevin's O5AB1E answer

Comment: Could be 11 if there were a reduce-right builtin :|

Comment: Why multiply by 2 after squaring?

Comment: @Falco the program checks if \$c^2 \times 2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2\$, which simplifies to pythagorean theorem

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 111 bytes

```
i:*&43::*{:}:*+\
/*::<5[1;?)&:&:/
\:{:}(?!v~1+31.
/]v?)}:{/|.!051+1~\
n \]~~>1+$:@$:@= ?^50.
\' 'o}:n' 'o}:nao$~$64.
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaToqJjQzOjoqezp9OiorXFxcbi8qOjo8NVsxOz8pJjomOi9cblxcOns6fSg/IXZ+MSszMS5cbi9ddj8pfTp7L3wuITA1MSsxflxcXG5uIFxcXX5+PjErJDpAJDpAPSA/XjUwLlxuXFwnICdvfTpuJyAnb306bmFvJH4kNjQuXG4gICAgICBcbiIsImlucHV0IjoiMjUiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

### Explanation

[image]

`><>` lacks a square root function so this simply tries all numbers until it finds one greater than the square of the inputs.

First, we square the input. We start searching at a,b=4,3. We check if \$a^2\$, (`::*`) + \$b^2\$ is more than the input squared, if so we exit.

Then we push 5, the starting third value. Square it, if it is more than a^2+b^2, go to the next iteration. Otherwise, add 1 to C.

If A^2+B^2=C^2, print A, B, and C, then go to next.

When we go to the next iteration, add 1 to B. If B>A, add 1 to A instead and reset B to 1. This is `1+$:@$:@=?~1+1`. Then we jump back to the start to try another iteration.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 63 bytes

```javascript
n=>{for(;p=n;n--)while(--p>(q=(n*n-p*p)**.5))q%1||print(q,p,n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcjBCkBAEADQu/9QM5sRipTWv0g2K43ZtXHAt6@Di@N7y3AM@@itBDraaHRk3V9m89CJ5o6J8JztOgGR9OA0sGISJahUXiO6tLxv8ZYDuEwyxicaqApMvsPEQP1H2WB8AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => {                  // n = input
  for(                  // outer loop:
    ;                   //
    p = n;              //   before each iteration, initialize p to n
                        //   stop when n = 0
    n--                 //   decrement n after each iteration
  )                     //
    while(              //   inner loop:
      --p > (           //     decrement p and test whether it's greater
        q =             //     than q defined as:
        (n * n - p * p) //       the square root of the difference
        ** .5           //       between n² and p²
      )                 //     stop as soon as the test fails
    )                   //
      q % 1 ||          //     if q is an integer:
        print(q, p, n)  //       print the triplet (q, p, n)
}                       //
```

Comment: I'm not aware of the "print" function in JavaScript. window.print() seems to print the currently open HTML document. I think you need console.log ?

Comment: @Falco This is a V8 instruction, which is unrelated to `window.print()`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this. Also your program errs on n=16 (printing 17,15,8 as a valid solution, but 17 > 16)

Comment: @Falco Thanks. Now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 81 bytes

```
n=>{for(a=0;++a<n;)for(b=a;b<n;++b)(c=(a*a+b*b)**.5)%1||c<=n&&console.log(a,b,c)}
```

Try it:

```js
f=n=>{for(a=0;++a<n;)for(b=a;b<n;++b)(c=(a*a+b*b)**.5)%1||c<=n&&console.log(a,b,c)}

;[
  1,
  3,
  5,
  7,
  10,
  17,
  20
].forEach(n=>{console.log(n+':');f(n)})
```

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hc1BCsIwEIXhfU/RjTATk9IoRSGMO08hQieBYl3EEks3tmePmW4@@DfvvXnhb0jjNJvlmgfKkW6/4ZOAKTpj2KGEJy7hHUIgYMVHrzwq1XR4sOs6pTHOwNrrgFt2j6qurS6chU64CLYVT231bMrmncML9jOI6PaJvt8w/wE)

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you! But I deliberately did not write such an option because of this is the @Aranuld's answer just with `for` instead of `while` :)

Comment: @Shaggy the shorter solution errs for n=16, because then c will be 17, which is too large

Comment: @PierrePaquette There are no duplicates in either my solution or Shaggy's solution.

Comment: Indeed; I just noticed I didn’t run Shaggy’s solution properly. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

### Scala, 71 bytes

```scala
(n:Int)=>for{c<-5 to n;b<-4 to c;a<-3 to b if a*a+b*b==c*c}yield(a,b,c)
```

or styled differently:

```scala
(n:Int)=>for{c<-5 to n
b<-4 to c
a<-3 to b
if a*a+b*b==c*c}yield(a,b,c)
```

It's not often that Scala gets a chance to do well in golfing, but the `.to()` method is perfect for inclusive ranges.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LcxLCsMgEADQfU4xS7URSj@bRgOlqx5jnBhqERWV0hJydttAd2/1CqHHFs3TUoUb2He1YSpwTQmW7oUeanbJ2wK6sXC5h8r1OMe8kJJnqBHCYJQ8baIBlTxuMuBmQIE7I4zWJGj9OOsnhr3pibf/yA57Dr/KIj0gZReqD93avg) or on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/l5yYoZfZQ8KwosbsySBJRQ)!

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 50 bytes

```
$=>[select combine.by:3@1..&'x[=+x\0^2x\1^2x\2^2]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?qVTI9Z)

```
$=>[                      ; an anonymous function
    select                ; select elements from a block
    combine.by:3 @1..&    ; combinations of 3 from the range 1 to n
    'x                    ; assign current triplet to x in the select
    [                     ; begin select
        =+x\0^2x\1^2x\2^2 ; is a^2+b^2 equal to c^2?
    ]                     ; end select
]                         ; end function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>91</s> 88 bytes

```python
lambda n,r=range:[(k,j,i)for i in r(1,n+1)for j in r(1,i)for k in r(1,j)if i*i==j*j+k*k]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3I3ISc5NSEhXydIpsixLz0lOtojWydbJ0MjXT8osUMhUy8xSKNAx18rQNwQJZMAGIfDaMm6WZmaaQqZVpa5ullaWdrZUdCzF_TUFRZl6JRpqGkYGmJkRowQIIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 12 bytes

```
RS3Lᵖ{:*Ɔ$∑=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FhuDgo19Hm6dVm2ldaxN5VHHRNslxUnJxVDZBUuMDLhMIWwA)

A port of [@Fatalize's Brachylog answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258636/9288).

```
RS3Lᵖ{:*Ɔ$∑=
R               Range from 1 to the input
 S              Subset
  3L            Length should be 3
    ᵖ{          Start a block; treat the block as a predicate,
                  and return the original value if the block does not fail
      :*        Multiply by itself
        Ɔ$∑=    The last element should equals to the sum of the other elements
```

By default, the Nekomata interpreter will print all possible results.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
ＩΣΣＥ⊕ＮＥιＥΦλ⁼×ιι⁺×λλ×νν⟦νλι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6Fjf7A4oy80o0nBOLSzSCS3PB2DexQMMzL7koNTc1ryQ1BcguKC3xK81NSi3S0NTUUQDJZ0Iot8ycEqBojo6Ca2FpYk6xRkhmbmoxSDYTqDAgpxQmAlSRAxSBcPJ0FPI0NUFGRQOZQKnMWE0IsF5SnJRcDHXc8mgl3bIcpdhFRgYQAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｎ                      Input integer
    ⊕                       Incremented
   Ｅ                        Map over implicit range
       ι                    Current value
      Ｅ                     Map over implicit range
          λ                 Current value
         Φ                  Filter over implicit range
            ×ιι             Square of outer value
           ⁼                Equals
                ×λλ         Square of inner value
               ⁺            Plus
                   ×νν      Square of innermost value
        Ｅ                   Map over matches
                      ⟦     List of
                       ν    Innermost value
                        λ   Inner value
                         ι  Outer value
  Σ                         Flatten
 Σ                          Flatten
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>112</s> 104 bytes

```python
lambda n,r=range:{(*sorted((i,j,k)),)for i in r(1,n+1)for j in r(1,n+1)for k in r(1,n+1)if i*i+j*j==k*k}
```

Literally the same thing as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒■■mÅ─╡gæ_▀s=gÆ²xε-┬▀
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EmPpi0AotzDrY@mNDyaujD98LL4R9Maim3TD7cd2lRxbqvuoylrgAL//xsZcJkCAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒         # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 ■        # Get the cartesian product with itself to create pairs
  ■       # Get the cartesian product with itself to create pairs of pairs
   m      # Map over each pair of pairs,
    Å     # using 2 characters as inner code-block:
     ─    #  Flatten the pair to a quadruplet
      ╡   #  Discard the last item to make it a triplet
 g        # Filter this list of triplets by,
  æ       # using 4 characters as inner code-block:
   _      #  Duplicate the current list
    ▀     #  Uniquify the values in the copy
     s    #  Sort it from lowest to highest
      =   #  Check if the two lists are still the same
 g        # Filter this list further by,
  Æ       # using 5 characters as inner code-block:
   ²      #  Square each integer in the triplet
    x     #  Reverse it
     ε    #  Reduce the triplet by:
      -   #   Subtracting
       ┬  #  Check if the result of this c²-b²-a² equals 0
 ▀        # After the filter: uniquify the remaining list of triplets
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
f!-F^R2_T.CSQ3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P01R1y0uyCg@RM85OND4/38jAwA)

#### Explanation

```
                  # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
         .C  3    # all sorted lists of three elements from
           SQ     # range(1,Q+1)
f                 # filter these lists on lambda T
       _T         #   reverse T
    ^R2           #   map elements to their squares
  -F              #   fold on subtraction (subtract all elements from the first)
 !                #   not (only true for zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 125 bytes

```
v
&
>35g:*25g:*+15g:*-|
  ,*52.g51.g52.g53<v
^p53+1_v#`\g52:g53<<
^111   >$135p25g:1 5g\`!#v_1+25p
^ p51+1_@#`g51\g51 :p521$<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsMgEETxul@xxdBDrKWr7KEioR8SjBRSb2UvEQr9d6s9zJthYOa5v4532e3dW/n8Y2sVzrB4LmF2A4YG7RcQLzO7a2HqGu5jhSTsDW1V57WXYZQRklIKEZeJPMs4IeSy5pOuGxnHAgmFqc8eOve7viQMwo6m2Jq7wQ8)

Note: The three "1"s shown here on line 6 ((1,5),(2,5) and (3,5) in Funge-Space) are actually be U+0001 in the source code. This is reflected correctly in TIO.

I may be able to save some bytes by moving those storage characters to line 1 or 2, and send line 6 left and wrap it, and if I can find a way to reduce the number of "g"s required to get the incremented values.

I'll do a nice writeup for this when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 98 bytes

Two solutions already exist for Python, but this one uses a slightly different approach that I thought might be informative:

```python
from itertools import *
lambda n:[(k,j,i)for(k,j,i)in combinations(range(0,n+1),3)if i*i==j*j+k*k]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
⟦₁⊇Ṫ.^₂ᵐṅᵗ+0∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG2oP/in6bigoHiiofhuaouXuKCguG1kOG5heG1lysw4oin//8yMP9a)

#### Explanation

This is a generator, which will unify with each triplet.

```
⟦₁                 Range [1, …, N]
  ⊇Ṫ.              Subset of 3 elements
     .^₂ᵐ          Square each element
         ṅᵗ        Negate the last one (which is the biggest)
           +0∧    The sum must be 0
```

#### Much faster, 19 bytes

```
≥~hṪ≥₁ℕ₁ᵐ^₂ᵐṅʰ+0∧Ṫ≜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bGh9sW/H/UubQu4@HOVUAaKPKoZSpIfOuEuEdNTUDq4c7WUxu0DR51LAcrmfP/v5GBwf8oAA)

Takes about 1.5s for N = 200 on TIO. This uses integer constraint programming mechanisms which is way more efficient than brute forcing combinations in a range, but is longer to express in this case.

```
≥~hṪ                 A triplet of elements whose head is smaller than N
    ≥₁               The triplet is non-increasing
      ℕ₁ᵐ            Each element is in [1, +inf)
         ^₂ᵐ         Map square
            ṅʰ       Negate the first element
              +0∧    The sum must be 0
                 Ṫ≜  Assign values to satisfy these constraints
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 113 + 7 bytes

Compiled with `-lm -DM=<input>`

```c
r,s,t;main(){for(;s<M;)for(t=++s;(r=sqrt(2*s*++t))<M;)r-sqrt(2*s*t)||(r+=s+t)>M||printf("%d %d %d\n",r-t,r-s,r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYlBCsIwEEWvIgVhpklAuo1x1W1u0E2JpBTaqDOzM169Y@tCeB8e/yU3paRKlq34dZwL4Ds/CDxfo8fDJBjDHijwiwS6lltjBPHI5P6fYK1AJvDebrHWJ81FMjTn@@nHUBpLTvaxJfQf1S3lZZxY3bKq62PoLl8)

Comment: [108 bytes + 7](https://tio.run/##HYnLCsIwEEV/RQrC5DEg3ca4cps/cFMiKYU26szsjL/u2Aj3wOHcjHPOquQ5bNNSQcy7PAgCn1Mw3SQ6xwEo8osERsvWOTGm32QJe5DWgFzkvV9Sa09aqhQYjvfDf7c6eELZYU8mfFS/uazTzIrrpnhNcTz9AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>85</s> 78 bytes

```
[range(3;.)]|combinations(3)|select(map(pow(.;2))|.[0]==.[1]+.[2]and.[1]>.[2])
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8X62UmVdQWqJkpaCno6CUX1oC5kT/L0rMS0/VMLHW06yJ1ovV1oDwjaF8zRo97ejcxAKNgvxyDT1rI03NmsSUlJriwqKS2Jri1JzU5BINvWijWFtbMFWTlpOfX6Sp@T@29r@hAZeRAZexAQA)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcexDsIgEADQna9omI5oLhQmbeqPkBuwEoOxB7U0DuK3Y@r23mNpHxk5b0WeOzx2Mm3lH9fcy/M9gB1QUZ3SfI3sS0y8glV1Dc8wFZh9hpzegINRqqLTNI7oejqgM@T5tvuyWzX6tpPotTBaWP0D)

Generates all triples, then filters.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 72 bytes

```js
c=>{for(a=b=c;c;--a||(a=--b)||(a=b=--c))c*c-b*b-a*a||console.log(c,b,a)}
```

Formatted:

```js
c => {
  for( a=b=c; c; /* until c is 0 */
     /* count down a, when a==0 reduce b and reset a=b, the same with c */
      --a || (a = --b) || (a = b = --c)
    )
    /* if c²-b²-a² == 0 log the tuple */
    c*c - b*b - a*a || console.log(c,b,a)
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TcnBCkBAFEbhvSeZO7mSUkrjXe79MyIZIRs8@5is7L7TmeSUHdu4Hnw20bsI110@bEacOrRomeW@UzErfdBEEMGC1SqLTR9h2cPcF3MYDHLNhZ7oTU3Zf1DmTVVSfAE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
q l=[(a,b,c)|c<-[1..l],a<-[1..c],b<-[a..l],a^2+b^2==c^2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1AhxzZaI1EnSSdZsybZRjfaUE8vJ1YnEcJKjtVJArISIWJxRtpJcUa2tslxRrH/cxMz82yLUhNTfPLs7GwLijLzSvQK/xsaAAA)